# Webpack watch not doing everything just running webpack does.

Tags: windows, webpack

Ok a picture is worth a 1000 words:

```
C:\gitrepo\dev\Web\Secured Account Access\Member [erochanges +101 ~4 -0 !]> webpack -d --watch
Webpack build starting: 1/8/2016 @ 11:26:38
clean-webpack-plugin: C:\gitrepo\dev\Web\Secured Account Access\Member\build\js has been removed.
Hash: 51337dd0be7daf80bbaf
Version: webpack 1.13.1
Time: 4923ms
                                         Asset       Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
         fetchpolyfill.0d39e51d8193e9047bf8.js    12.7 kB          [emitted]
    babel-polyfill.a0f0baed01fffd04dd66.min.js  242 bytes       0  [emitted]  babel-polyfill
    errorValidator.92845383126defed29e7.min.js  246 bytes       2  [emitted]  errorValidator
     fetchpolyfill.0d39e51d8193e9047bf8.min.js    7.01 kB       3  [emitted]  fetchpolyfill
    paymentoptions.217e18de338d68b7686f.min.js      12 kB       4  [emitted]  paymentoptions
            common.1524774d345143c7bf98.min.js     170 kB       5  [emitted]  common
        babel-polyfill.a0f0baed01fffd04dd66.js  260 bytes          [emitted]
               confirm.0169b72e33797a5d8946.js    17.3 kB          [emitted]
        errorValidator.92845383126defed29e7.js  264 bytes          [emitted]
           confirm.0169b72e33797a5d8946.min.js    5.83 kB       1  [emitted]  confirm
        paymentoptions.217e18de338d68b7686f.js    21.7 kB          [emitted]
                common.1524774d345143c7bf98.js     450 kB          [emitted]
babel-polyfill.a0f0baed01fffd04dd66.min.js.map  667 bytes       0  [emitted]  babel-polyfill
       confirm.0169b72e33797a5d8946.min.js.map      41 kB       1  [emitted]  confirm
errorValidator.92845383126defed29e7.min.js.map  671 bytes       2  [emitted]  errorValidator
 fetchpolyfill.0d39e51d8193e9047bf8.min.js.map    34.2 kB       3  [emitted]  fetchpolyfill
paymentoptions.217e18de338d68b7686f.min.js.map    57.3 kB       4  [emitted]  paymentoptions
        common.1524774d345143c7bf98.min.js.map    1.06 MB       5  [emitted]  common
   [0] multi babel-polyfill 28 bytes {0} [built]
   [0] ./confirm.js 3.07 kB {1} [built]
   [0] multi errorValidator 28 bytes {2} [built]
   [0] multi fetchpolyfill 28 bytes {3} [built]
   [0] multi paymentoptions 28 bytes {4} [built]
 [314] ./errorValidator.js 757 bytes {5} [built]
 [315] ./vendor/fetchpolyfill.js 52 bytes {3} {4} [built]
 [317] ./paymentoptions.js 8.56 kB {4} [built]
    + 314 hidden modules
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Hash: dfaf3d5b8e90ad0cbbd1
Version: webpack 1.13.1
Time: 3431ms
                                  Asset       Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
    confirm.4223b8e2ab9faa4d53bd.min.js    5.83 kB       1  [emitted]  confirm
     common.d88bf4fa955260af5738.min.js     170 kB       5  [emitted]  common
 babel-polyfill.a0f0baed01fffd04dd66.js  260 bytes          [emitted]
        confirm.4223b8e2ab9faa4d53bd.js    17.3 kB          [emitted]
 errorValidator.92845383126defed29e7.js  264 bytes          [emitted]
  fetchpolyfill.0d39e51d8193e9047bf8.js    12.7 kB          [emitted]
 paymentoptions.217e18de338d68b7686f.js    21.7 kB          [emitted]
         common.d88bf4fa955260af5738.js     450 kB          [emitted]
confirm.4223b8e2ab9faa4d53bd.min.js.map      41 kB       1  [emitted]  confirm
 common.d88bf4fa955260af5738.min.js.map    1.06 MB       5  [emitted]  common
   [0] ./confirm.js 3.06 kB {1} [built]
    + 321 hidden modules
```

The first time i start up the watch everything is happening as i expect. As soon as i save a change and webpack is kicked off you will noticed two steps are missed (i put a dashed line to help distinguish between the first call and second call):

1. 1 plugin i'm using (`clean-webpack-plugin`) isn't being callled
2. Console.log statement i have at the top of my webpack.config file isn't being called.

Here is my webpack.config.js file:

```
/// <binding ProjectOpened='Watch - Development' />
let fs = require('fs');
let path = require('path');
let webpack = require('webpack');
let currentDate = new Date();


console.log("Webpack build starting: " +
    currentDate.getDate() +
    "/" +
    (currentDate.getMonth() + 1) +
    "/" +
    currentDate.getFullYear() +
    " @ " +
    currentDate.getHours() +
    ":" +
    currentDate.getMinutes() +
    ":" +
    currentDate.getSeconds());

//webpack plugins
let cleanWebPackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
let assetPlugin = require('assets-webpack-plugin');
let webpackOnBuildPlugin = require('on-build-webpack');


let isProd = (JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV.replace(/\"/g, "") || 'prod') === '"prod"');

let plugins = [
    new cleanWebPackPlugin(['build/js'], {
        root: path.resolve('.'),
        verbose: true,
        dry: false
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin('common', 'common.[chunkhash].min.js', 3),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
        compress: {
            warnings: false
        }
    }),
    new assetPlugin(
    {
        path: path.resolve('build/js/')
    }),
    new webpackOnBuildPlugin(function (stats) {
        if (!isProd) {
            //when in dev return the regular file instead of the minified file.
            String.prototype.replaceAll = function (search, replacement) {
                var target = this;
                return target.split(search).join(replacement);
            };

            fs.readFile(path.resolve('build/js/webpack-assets.json'), 'utf8', function (err, data) {
                var results = data.replaceAll(".min", "");
                fs.writeFile(path.resolve('build/js/webpack-assets.json'),
                    results,
                    "utf8",
                    function (err) {
                        if (err) return console.log(err);
                    });
            });
        }
    })
];


if (!isProd) {
    let unminifiedWebpackPlugin = require('unminified-webpack-plugin');
    plugins.push(new unminifiedWebpackPlugin());
}

module.exports = {
    context: path.resolve('scripts'),
    entry: {
        confirm: "./confirm",
        "fetchpolyfill": ["./vendor/fetchpolyfill"],
        "errorValidator": ["./errorValidator"],
        'paymentoptions': ["./paymentoptions"],
        'babel-polyfill': ['babel-polyfill']
    },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve('build/js/'),
        publicPath: '/build/js/',
        chunkFilename: "[name]" + ".[chunkhash].js",
        filename: "[name]" + ".[chunkhash].min.js"
    },
    plugins: plugins,
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.es6$/,
                exclude: ["/Scripts/vendor/", "node_modules"],
                loader: "babel-loader"
            }
        ]
    },

    resolve: {
        extensions: ["", ".js", ".es6"]
    }

}
```

Why is my console.log missed, and more importantely, my `clean-webpack-plugin`?